# How to add crosshair cursor in 2D and 3D rendering?

Tags: xtk

In the 2D renders, such as in Lesson 13 (http://lessons.goxtk.com/13/), is it possible to add a crosshair cursor indicating the position of orthogonal slices, like this [sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tCfV.png)?

Furthermore, is it possible to show that crosshair in the 3D volume render, instead of showing three orthogonal slices?